# Matrix multiplication of matrix sequences

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I searched for a way to do a sequential matrix multiplication 
similarly to the sum(A,dim) or prod(A,dim) operations do for the sum or the element-wise multiplication.

for example:

```
A = arrayfun(@(x) rand(5), 1:n, 'UniformOutput', false);
P = A{1} * A{2} * ... * A{n};  % <-- search for an elegant way to do this
```

I would use it to multiply a large number of Transfer matrices.

Comment: If you are looking for performance, go with a initialization based loopy solution.

Comment: Do all `A` have the same dimensions? Then you could [try this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8773-multiple-matrix-multiplications--with-array-expansion-enabled).

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop for this. It is what an 'elegant' method would do eventually.

```
P = A{1};
for i=2:length(A), P = P * A{i}, end
```